# how to write a text and calculation in a same time like Calcnote app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

I try lots of things but I failed kindly help me with how to do this and please someone shares a complete.  I also share a screenshot of the original app I making same like this app.

App description:
1:When typing or calculating on the app if the user needs the next line and show a list num
2: The most important thing is when we calculate any num can we write something in the same type ( you think it's a notepad + calculator)?
3: Also when we write and type 5 + 5 we don't need to press = equal to. they abstract and subtract automatically.

thank you so much for your support.

Comment: this is not a code writer website. At first, you try it. If it's not working well then we will help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.